# How to add an on Select event to an Auto complete combobox?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, combobox, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have this Combobox

[image]

```
@change call API + populated list - Done ✅
@select doSomething() - Not Done ❌
```

I have a hard time detecting what was selected. Ex. If I select "Massachusetts" I want to access that.

```
<v-col md="8">
    <v-combobox :items="locations" v-model="rule.value" :label="Name" @change="getLocations(index, rule, rule.attribute_id)" @click="selectLocation(index, rule, rule.attribute_id)"></v-combobox>
</v-col>

<v-col md="12" v-if="rule.operator_id == 15">
    <v-textarea v-model="inListLocations" label="Locations" dense outlined></v-textarea>
</v-col>
```

Comment: Just to understand the requirement in more clear way, May I know the use case of `@click` ? As `@change` will work in both the cases (option selection as well as on focus out after typing)

Comment: On change will go to get the matched string from API states could be thousand. Then when I see what I like, I selected. When I selected I want to access it and add it to a new list. It diff than on change.

Comment: What I understood is that on change you want to make an API call and then you have to bind the response in the `textarea`. Is my understanding correct ? If Yes, then i think no need to use `@click` event.

Comment: `@change` call API + populated list `@select` doSomething()

Comment: @RohìtJíndal `@click` not doing anything. I want to doSomething when the user select from the selected list.

Comment: `@change` will help you to `doSomething` when the user select from the selected list. you can achieve both call API as well as doSomething.

Answer (score 2):

Give a `@change="onChange"` event to your component.

```
<v-autocomplete
        v-model="values"
        :items="items"
        outlined
        dense
        item-text="name"
        item-value="id"
        return-object
        @change="onChange"
        @input="onInput"
        label="Outlined"
        multiple
      ></v-autocomplete>

data(){
   return {
     items: [
       { id: 1, name: "LIMASSOL DISTRICT (LEYMASUN)" }
       { id: 2, name: "LA MASSANA" }
     ]
   }
},
methods:{
  onChange(item){
     console.log("on change:   ", item);  // Now you should have access to your selected option.
     this.getItems(item.id);  // Here send your item id and request for details.
  },
  onInput(item){
    console.log("on input:   ", item);
  },
  async getItems(id){ 
    const response = await this.$axios.get('items/'+ id);
    this.yourData = response.data?.yourData;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if @change is what I am looking for. I told that I tried that already.

Comment: Please see my comments above with Rohit.

Comment: I have edited my code take a look if you want something like that. I read your comments and again it's not clear enough. If it didn't help then please provide a sample of your output which you want to get.

Comment: I appreciated your help so far. I will make it clear. 

@change="onChange" must spell exactly that or no ???

Comment: I also update my post clearly state what I want.

Comment: `@change` is the event which calls a method named `onChange`. You can change your method name if you want, but don't change `@change` which is a build in event.

Answer (score 0):

You should use @keydown with @change, and wrap the api call function with setTimeout - for debounce. And trigger your api call for every event you want together!

Comment: async updateValue() {
      const waitTime = 850;
      clearTimeout(this.updateValueTimer);
      this.updateValueTimer = setTimeout(async () => {
        await this.apiCall();
      }, waitTime);
    },